# How to write multi column in clause with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Please suggest is there way to write query multi-column in clause using SQLAlchemy?

Here is example of the actual query:

```
SELECT  url FROM pages WHERE (url_crc, url) IN ((2752937066, 'http://members.aye.net/~gharris/blog/'), (3799762538, 'http://www.coxandforkum.com/'));
```

I have a table that has two columns primary key and I'm hoping to avoid adding one more key just to be used as an index.

PS I'm using mysql DB.

**Update:** This query will be used for batch processing - so I would need to put few hundreds pairs into the in clause. With IN clause approach I hope to know fixed limit of how many pairs I can stick into one query. Like Oracle has 1000 enum limit by default.

Using AND/OR combination might be limited by the length of the query in chars. Which would be variable and less predictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the test() based solution: generated "(a,b) in ((:a1, :b1), (:a2,:b2), ...)" with named bind vars and generating dictionary with bind vars' values.

```
params = {}
for counter, r in enumerate(records):
    a_param = "a%s" % counter
    params[a_param] = r['a']
    b_param = "b%s" % counter
    params[b_param] = r['b']
    pair_text = "(:%s,:%s)" % (a_param, b_param)
    enum_pairs.append(pair_text)
multicol_in_enumeration = ','.join(enum_pairs)
multicol_in_clause = text(
    " (a,b) in (" + multicol_in_enumeration + ")")
q = session.query(Table.id, Table.a,
                            Table.b).filter(multicol_in_clause).params(params)
```

Another option I thought about using mysql upserts but this would make whole included even less portable for the other db engine then using multicolumn in clause.

**Update** SQLAlchemy has [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_(*clauses, **kw)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=text%20function#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) construct that can be used for the same purpose. (I haven't tried it yet)

Answer (score 19):

Assuming that you have your model defined in `Page`, here's an example using [`tuple_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_):

```py
keys = [
    (2752937066, 'http://members.aye.net/~gharris/blog/'),
    (3799762538, 'http://www.coxandforkum.com/')
]
    
select([
    Page.url
]).select_from(
    Page
).where(
    tuple_(Page.url_crc, Page.url).in_(keys)
)
```

Or, using the query API:

```py
session.query(Page.url).filter(tuple_(Page.url_crc, Page.url).in_(keys))
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is currently possible in sqlalchemy, and not all RDMBS support this.
You can always transform this to a `OR(AND...)` condition though:

```
filter_rows = [
    (2752937066, 'http://members.aye.net/~gharris/blog/'),
    (3799762538, 'http://www.coxandforkum.com/'),
    ]
qry = session.query(Page)
qry = qry.filter(or_(*(and_(Page.url_crc == crc, Page.url == url) for crc, url in filter_rows)))
print qry
```

should produce something like (for SQLite):

```
SELECT  pages.id AS pages_id, pages.url_crc AS pages_url_crc, pages.url AS pages_url
FROM    pages
WHERE   pages.url_crc = ? AND pages.url = ? OR pages.url_crc = ? AND pages.url = ?
-- (2752937066L, 'http://members.aye.net/~gharris/blog/', 3799762538L, 'http://www.coxandforkum.com/')
```

**Alternatively**, you can combine two columns into just one:

```
filter_rows = [
    (2752937066, 'http://members.aye.net/~gharris/blog/'),
    (3799762538, 'http://www.coxandforkum.com/'),
    ]
qry = session.query(Page)
qry = qry.filter((func.cast(Page.url_crc, String) + '|' + Page.url).in_(["{}|{}".format(*_frow) for _frow in filter_rows]))
print qry
```

which produces the below (for SQLite), so you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT  pages.id AS pages_id, pages.url_crc AS pages_url_crc, pages.url AS pages_url
FROM    pages
WHERE   (CAST(pages.url_crc AS VARCHAR) || ? || pages.url) IN (?, ?)
-- ('|', '2752937066|http://members.aye.net/~gharris/blog/', '3799762538|http://www.coxandforkum.com/')
```

Comment: It is viable idea. But won't fit my need. I've extended the question with more details.

Comment: Updated answer with the `IN` versionn as well.

Comment: Thanks for update. I thought about combining two columns into one string - but this would be slow - as no index would be used in this case.

Comment: I see. well, given the "batch" nature of the task, maybe you should consider using pure SQL and even try to avoid the IN clause all together as it is not famous to be very fast on most databases. Good luck and please share your decision. Thanks