# Using sqlalchemy to query using multiple column where in clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm looking to execute this query using sqlalchemy.

```
SELECT name,
       age,
       favorite_color,
       favorite_food
FROM kindergarten_classroom
WHERE (favorite_color,
       favorite_food) IN (('lavender','lentil soup'),('black','carrot juice'));
```

I only want kids that like (lavender AND lentil soup) OR (black and carrot juice). Also, this will probably be a huge list of favorite colors and foods (likely > 10K), so I'll want to do these in large batches.

This is similar, but doesn't get me all of the way there:
[Sqlalchemy in clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20461887/1632891

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want the [`tuple_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) construct:

```
session.query(...).filter(
    tuple_(favorite_color, favorite_food).in_(
        [('lavender', 'lentil soup'), ('black', 'carrot juice')]
    )
)
```