# filter on multiple columns in subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, subquery, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to be able to filter on a multiple column row in a subquery

In sql this would be something like

```
where (account_details.account_detail_id, tasks.base_action_type_id)  IN 
(
SELECT tasks.account_detail_id  , tasks.base_action_type_id
FROM tasks 
WHERE tasks.dt_created > now() - interval '1 day'
GROUP BY tasks.account_detail_id ,tasks.base_action_type_id
HAVING count(tasks.account_detail_id) < 3
)
```

But I Cannot find any information on the format for sqlalchmey

I tried

```
dayBefore = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)

subquery = Tasks.query.with_entities(Tasks.account_detail_id, Tasks.base_action_type_id).\
    filter(Tasks.dt_created >  dayBefore).\
    group_by(Tasks.account_detail_id, Tasks.base_action_type_id).\
    having(func.count(Tasks.account_detail_id) < 3)

sql = AccountDetails.query.join(Tasks, Tasks.account_detail_id == AccountDetails.account_detail_id).\
    filter(AccountDetails.account_detail_id == 3,  (AccountDetails.account_detail_id,Tasks.base_action_type_id).in_(subquery))
```

Note the line

```
(AccountDetails.account_detail_id,Tasks.base_action_type_id).in_(subquery)
```

But that just errors out as invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

well as usual, hours of searching before posting found nothing. First search after posting question found the answer

[Using sqlalchemy to query using multiple column where in clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436838/using-sqlalchemy-to-query-using-multiple-column-where-in-clause)